# Statsmodels gives error: exog contains inf or nans, but I do not have any nan of inf in the data

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have an issue when using Statsmodels to make a regression analysis.

I have 4 different dependent variables that I want to test one after the other. For 3 of them every things works fine, but when I use the last one I get the following error:
But I tried everything to figure out if there are any nan`s or inf in the data and the analysis shows there is not. Is there any other potential cause of the error?

To check for nan and inf I used:

```
x.isna().sum()
```

Which gives 0

```
if (x.isin([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan]).any()):
    print("Series contains infinite values")
else:
    print("Series does not contain infinite values")
```

Which prints Series does not contain infinite values

```
----> 5     result = sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant(x_adj)).fit()
      6     return result

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    870     def __init__(self, endog, exog=None, missing='none', hasconst=None,
    871                  **kwargs):
--> 872         super(OLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
    873                                   hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
    874         if "weights" in self._init_keys:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, weights, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    701         else:
    702             weights = weights.squeeze()
--> 703         super(WLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
    704                                   weights=weights, hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
    705         nobs = self.exog.shape[0]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    188     """
    189     def __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs):
--> 190         super(RegressionModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
    191         self._data_attr.extend(['pinv_wexog', 'weights'])
    192 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    235 
    236     def __init__(self, endog, exog=None, **kwargs):
--> 237         super(LikelihoodModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
    238         self.initialize()
    239 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
     75         missing = kwargs.pop('missing', 'none')
     76         hasconst = kwargs.pop('hasconst', None)
---> 77         self.data = self._handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst,
     78                                       **kwargs)
     79         self.k_constant = self.data.k_constant

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in _handle_data(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
     99 
    100     def _handle_data(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs):
--> 101         data = handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    102         # kwargs arrays could have changed, easier to just attach here
    103         for key in kwargs:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    670 
    671     klass = handle_data_class_factory(endog, exog)
--> 672     return klass(endog, exog=exog, missing=missing, hasconst=hasconst,
    673                  **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
     85         self.const_idx = None
     86         self.k_constant = 0
---> 87         self._handle_constant(hasconst)
     88         self._check_integrity()
     89         self._cache = {}

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py in _handle_constant(self, hasconst)
    131             exog_max = np.max(self.exog, axis=0)
    132             if not np.isfinite(exog_max).all():
--> 133                 raise MissingDataError('exog contains inf or nans')
    134             exog_min = np.min(self.exog, axis=0)
    135             const_idx = np.where(exog_max == exog_min)[0].squeeze()

MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans
```

Comment: Did you check dtype and values of the problematic variable? The relevant check is `np.isfinite` which is false if it's not finite, non-nan numbers.